# Activity is getting too large and becoming more and more difficult to work with. Solutions to solve this issue?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am working on my second Android Application, first being, hello world.  The application code is quite crazy looking because I love to test new libraries and ideas in it.  I have been working on this application for well over 3 months and one of my activities is getting way to large and difficult to work with.  I find myself getting lost in the code and it is taking longer to do simple things.  There might be simple solutions to solving this issue.  I really want to split my activity into two and reference each other if possible. Is there are any suggestions to simplifying and organizing code that would be greatly helpful.  Even example will help me very much.

Part of my activity is adding a ton of data into a database and the other part is a long equation with multiple values.  Another part is implementing the HoloGraphLibrary (Which I love).  It is also implementing a listView with custom adapter.  It also has a custom dialog............   I can go on and on.  I hope you get my point.

**EDIT**

Going to work with this.

```
HoloGraphHelper holoGraph = new HoloGraphHelper();
holoGraph.initialize();
```

Comment: "I really want to split my activity " ... what's holding you back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating classes for each responsibility.

A Database Helper that has functions to insert data too:

```
DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper();
database .insertData(whatever);
```

A HoloGraphHelper that initializes the HoloGraph

```
HoloGraphHelper holoGraph = new HoloGraphHelper();
holoGraph.initialize();
```

And so on.

Comment: Take a look at the Edit.  Is that how I would start the second activity?

Comment: I am starting to get what you are saying.  
I need to do a little more research on how to develop a helper.  
I understand the databseHelper because I have been recently working with them.  Let me get back to you in a moment

Comment: No, keep a single Activity. Initialize the helpers in onCreate. Also look into Fragments.

Comment: Yes, I think fragments are going to be my best bet because they are all interconnected.  Since I am storing data in a database I belive it will be easier to work with the fragments because I wont have to send data to the mainactivity.  I can just pull it from the database.  I have been avoiding fragments because I had trouble when I first started working with android.  I think I will be easier at this point after learning much in the past month.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Break into multiple files. First classes defined in the Activity like the adapter. Change anonymous classes to classes defined in their own file. Look for ways to break out other related code into a class.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on src folder of your Project and select new - class to create a new class. You can use a class for storing methods but you won't be able to display anything on screen.
To display contents to user, you can create a new Activity bu pressing Ctrl + N and selecting Android - Android Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is modularise your code.

I.e split your code into various related modules, for example a separate class for each part that your testing. So you could have a database entry class, a class for Gui testing, i.e. for your custom dialog. That class does all the work for that test, into various functions, I always try to keep functions as small as possible as they are easy to read.

As an example for your database entry, you could have a function which checks the database if the record already exists and then insert it. But a better way would be your insert function only performs the insert code and instead within this function it calls CheckIfDatAlreadyExists function which can return a bool so you know whether you should go ahead and insert the record. This would keep the code tidy and clean to manage.

Then from your main activity all would need to do is instantiate the relative class and call the relevant method.